# If div text equals certain text do something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Cannot for the life of me get this to work. Even when removing the AJAX POST function, it still doesn't work. There is no alert or anything. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abwp5u21/) and code:

HTML

```
<div class="notification">
            <div class="title gooddog">test</div>
            <div class="reason helvetica"></div>
        </div>
<script>
    var interval = setInterval(function(){

      var Winner = $(".notification .title gooddog").text();
      if(Winner == "test") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "Won.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: { Winner : Winner }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log('foo', data);
        });
      }

    },1000);
</script>
```

It is meant to trigger/check the div text for changes every 1 seconds, but as you can see, it's doing nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Winner = $(".notification .title gooddog").text();
```

should be

```
var Winner = $(".notification .title.gooddog").text();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abwp5u21/8/

Answer (score 0):

You've got several issues...

1. You are using jQuery syntax but you are not including the jQuery plugin...at least not in the fiddle
2. Not an issue in this case, but if you want to get whatever is inside a `div` use the `html` function rather than the `text` function
3. As @Cattla pointed out in her answer to the proper "multi-class" selector is `.title.gooddog`

I wouldn't be surprised if you had more issues on the server-side as well. Here's an updated [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/abwp5u21/12/)